# How to automatically refresh gdb in tui mode?

Tags: python, linux, gdb, gnu-screen, tui

If I'am debugging files with `gdb -tui` the source window always becomes messed up. So every time I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> I have to immediately type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get rid of this problem, this is how `gdb` refeshes the window. I am working on tty with gnu screen.

Is there a possibility to automatically refresh gdb in tui mode?
If gdb doesn't have this ability Python could be a solution because gdb is able to source Python files, but I don't know about Python.

This Python snippet works fine in Bash but not inside gdb:

```
import sys
r = "\033[2J"    # here I try to emulate [ctrl-L]
t = ""
while 1:
    i = sys.stdin.read(1)
    t = t +i
    if i == '\n':
        print(r)
```

Of course I accept every other language supported by gdb.
Every help is appreciated.

By the way, here is a screencast https://youtu.be/DqiH6Jym1JY that show my problem.

This is the file I used for demonstrating in gdb like the link above show's, mess_up.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    //int n = 120;
    int n;
    n = 120;
    char stuff[n+2];

    printf( "Max: %d\n", n );

    printf( "Sizeof int:  %d\n", sizeof(int)  );
    printf( "Sizeof char: %d\n", sizeof(char) );
    printf( "Sizeof n:  %d\n", sizeof n   );
    printf( "Sizeof stuff: %d\n", sizeof stuff  );

    fgets ( stuff , n , stdin );
    printf( "The stuff:\n%s\n", stuff );
    printf( "Sizeof stuff after input = %d\n", sizeof stuff  );

return 0;
}
```

My actual ncurses version displayed by `tic -V` is `ncurses 5.9.20140118`

Comment: Screen may be your issue.  Personally, I find working that working with gdb from within emacs via `M-gdb` works really well, as the integration handles following the source files in a separate window which you give commands to gdb itself.

Comment: I have the same problems if I only work on tty without screen. I can't believe gdb works just proper with emacs

Comment: Some examples with images/videos: http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html

Comment: Ooh, this is really overwhelming me that I should keep trying on pressing [ctrl]-[l]. I just know some basic vim commands and my c projects does  have at most only 3 or 4 files with source files that have 40 lines at least. This is a little bit to much for refeshing a tty screen.

Comment: Workaround: (a) create a new terminal window (b) type `tty` in the new window to get the tty name, which will look like `/dev/pts/2` (c) type `sleep 99999` to get the shell out of the way (d) in the gdb tui command window, type `tty /dev/pts/2` (or whatever the tty name is), then `run` as you would normally.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've tried this out. But It just wrotes the output to the tty with the sleep command and when a `fgets()` command occurs in gdb it hangs so that I have to hit `ctrl+c`.

Comment: Please enter any tty input for your program by typing it in the new window.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, I think I followed your instruction. Screen is running in /dev/pts/1, then I open a new window, it's /dev/pts2, there I type sleep n-seconds, while it's sleeping I go to /dev/pts/1, run gdb, there I type tty /dev/pts/2, I load my file, type b main, then run and it looks, that it doesn't mess up anymore the source window. I step through my file, by the way the output is written to /dev/pts/2 with a warning ahead, gdb failed to set controlling, but if I step in gdb to a c function call fgets, gdb hangs.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your problem. What distribution (name and version number) of Linux are you running?

Comment: Okay, nice, `uname -r` prints `Linux goofy 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:32 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` and `lsb_release -a` prints `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty`. gdb version is 7.11.1

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 14.04.5, and stepping up to an fgets does cause gdb to hang, but only because it's waiting for target process's __read_nocancel (called by fgets) to return. Once I type something in the other terminal window, I get a `(gdb)` prompt again. I'm using `layout split`. Do you have a simple program (I'm just using `while(fgets(...)!=NULL) fputs(...)` that causes gdb to hang?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, I have posted the example source I am using and my actual version of ncurses additionally to my question. I am also using the `layout split`.

Comment: Hi @JohnGoofy, have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same problem on macOS now :(

Comment: @SunQingyao No, I didn't. Even with `emacs` I have similarly issues.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I like your workaround, as it solve the mentioned display issue and it seperates gdb from any console output of the program

Comment: I lay witness that 5 years later, the situation has no improved whatsoever. If gdb wasn't the only debugger that exists for linux systems, I would swear it's abandonware

Comment: same issue 8 years later

Answer (score 23):

Had the exact same problem.
Have you tried GDB user-defined hooks or commands ?

In your ~/.gdbinit or in your session, you can do:

```
define hook-next
  refresh
end
```

This will call the `refresh` command each time you enter the `next` command or one of its aliases.

Or you can define:

```
define mynext
  next
  refresh
end
```

and call `mynext` instead of `next`.

Hooks are automatically called whenever a command C is entered and a hook-C exists, that's so cool, I've just discovered that in the docs.

See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html
and https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks

You can add as many hooks/defines as you want.

Comment: Is there any reason reason for gdb not refresh itself by default ?

Comment: because most of the time it shouldn't need to, so it's a lot of work for no reason...

Answer (score 10):

Partially related: I put this in my ~/.gdbinit and it successfully refreshes the TUI after I use `c` and `n`, which were the commands usually causing TUI cruft in my case.

```
define c 
  continue
  refresh
end

define n
  next
  refresh
end
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Otherwise I have to manually type in refresh every time. So annoying!